# sqlite query, searching by specific dates

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to search an sqlite3 db that I created in Python, but the query isn't working.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM pitches WHERE pitcher = ' + str(home_pitcher_id) + ' AND estimated_woba_using_speedangle > 0 AND strftime("%Y-%m-%d", game_date) <= ' + game_date + ' ORDER BY game_date DESC LIMIT ' + str(x_most_recent_pitches))
```

I built it one piece at a time, and it worked until I added

```
AND strftime("%Y-%m-%d", game_date) <= ' + game_date
```

I've tried making the data type for "game_date" both Text and Date, neither seems to matter.

The game_date value for an example row is:
    '2018-8-7'

It appears to be a string no matter what data type I select. I tried the strftime function because in the sqlite db the month and day have 1 digit sometimes. I've also tried it without the strftime function, same result.

The problem isn't that the query doesn't run; it does. I don't get any errors or anything. It just doesn't find any results. If I take the date specific out, it works fine.

Comment: Your date needs to look like `'2018-08-07'`. Note the leading 0's.

Comment: Also, read up on how to use parameters in your query and bind values to them instead of trying to build a string with values directly embedded in it like you're doing. Just say no to introducing opportunities for SQL injection.

Comment: Is there a quick way to edit the date column in the database to format the dates? I thought that's what I was doing with the strftime function. The database was built from a couple of csv files, and is about 1 GB, so if there's a way to do it without going back to the CSVs that would be ideal.

Comment: If the values in the `game_date` column aren't in one of the formats understood by sqlite data and time functions, they'll just return `null`. So you have to write something that fixes the columns. Personally, unless you can just delete the table and re-insert all your data in the right format, I'd write a user-defined function in python that fixes the values and use that in an update statement. Sqlite string manipulation functions are really basic and not well suited to this sort of thing.

Comment: Learn to use parameters when running queries from Python.